# Callbacks on Multiple AJAX request termination

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

**SOLVED - Due to a Simple Mistake in the HTML that messed up the associated Javascript**

I'm trying to issue a callback using ".ajaxStop" after a series of many AJAX requests have been issued.  However, my code is not invoking the callback after the requests have finished.

Here is my code:

```
    $.getJSON('https://graph.facebook.com/me/mutualfriends/' + 
              friendArray[i] + "?access_token=" + accessToken, 
        (function(index) {
for (var i = 0; i < friendArray.length; i++){
        return function(dataJSON2) {
            resultArray = dataJSON2['data'];

            resultJSON += '"' + friendArray[index] + '"' + ":" + resultArray.length;

            if (index != friendArray.length - 1){
                resultJSON += ",";
            }else {
                resultJSON += "}";
            }
        }
    }) (i));    
}

$('#messageContainer').ajaxStop( function() {
    $(this).html(resultJSON);
});
```

Each of the callbacks for my AJAX requests are correctly put in a closured callback but when I wait for the ajaxStop method to trigger, nothing happens.

Comment: Not sure if it applies in this case, but you should probably register your ajaxStop handler _before_ issuing any Ajax requests.

Comment: Valid point but in this case I doubt it would matter since the ajaxStop callback would be prepared long before the last .getJSON request is made.

Comment: exactly, that's why I was doubting whether it would apply or not.

Answer (score 0):

You have a scope and timing issue.  'Scope' because the variable `resultJSON` only exists within your `$.getJSON` callback method.  'Timing' because even if you managed to share the `resultJSON` variable, due to the asynchronous nature of the `$.getJSON` method, the `resultJSON` variable wouldn't populate in time to be used inside the `$.ajaxStop` method.

Comment: Sorry.  Forgot to show that I did instantiate resultJSON outside of the $.getJSON method.  So, I would have to create  "setTimeout" that repeatedly calls $.ajaxStop?